# Sorting ListView Columns

Tags: c#, sorting, wpf

I use these codes to re-order columns in a `ListView` in ascending or descending order:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<Inventory> SortedDailyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Inventory> SortedCustomCollection = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>();
    bool isDaily = true;
    bool descAsc = true;
    bool suppAsc = true;
    bool soldAsc = true;

    private void lvProductsColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
        string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();
        if (listViewSortCol != null)
        {
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Remove(listViewSortAdorner);
        }

        ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        if (listViewSortCol == column && listViewSortAdorner.Direction == newDir)
            newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

        listViewSortCol = column;
        listViewSortAdorner = new SortAdorner(listViewSortCol, newDir);
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Add(listViewSortAdorner);
        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case "Description":
                SortDescription();
                break;
            case "Supplier":
                SortSupplier();
                break;
            case "Sold":
                SortSold();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private void SortDescription()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Inventory> chosenCollection = (isDaily) ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;
        List<Inventory> InventoryList = chosenCollection.ToList();
        InventoryList = (descAsc) ? InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderBy(r => r.ProductDescription).ToList() : InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderByDescending(r => r.ProductDescription).ToList();
        var tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>(InventoryList);
        chosenCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var item in tempCollection)
        {
            Inventory _inventory = new Inventory
            {
                ProductDescription = item.ProductDescription,
                Supplier = item.Supplier,
                ProductSold = item.ProductSold,
                ProductCost = item.ProductCost,
                ProductRetail = item.ProductRetail,
                TotalRetail = item.TotalRetail
            };
            chosenCollection.Add(_inventory);
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = chosenCollection;
        if (descAsc)
        {
            descAsc = false;
            suppAsc = true;
            soldAsc = true;
        }
        else
        {
            descAsc = true;
        }
    }
    private void SortSupplier()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Inventory> chosenCollection = (isDaily) ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;
        List<Inventory> InventoryList = chosenCollection.ToList();
        InventoryList = (suppAsc) ? InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderBy(r => r.Supplier).ToList() : InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderByDescending(r => r.Supplier).ToList();
        var tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>(InventoryList);
        chosenCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var item in tempCollection)
        {
            Inventory _inventory = new Inventory
            {
                ProductDescription = item.ProductDescription,
                Supplier = item.Supplier,
                ProductSold = item.ProductSold,
                ProductCost = item.ProductCost,
                ProductRetail = item.ProductRetail,
                TotalRetail = item.TotalRetail
            };
            chosenCollection.Add(_inventory);
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = chosenCollection;
        if (suppAsc)
        {
            descAsc = true;
            suppAsc = false;
            soldAsc = true;
        }
        else
        {
            suppAsc = true;
        }
    }
    private void SortSold()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Inventory> chosenCollection = (isDaily) ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;
        List<Inventory> InventoryList = chosenCollection.ToList();
        InventoryList = (soldAsc) ? InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderByDescending(r => r.ProductSold).ToList() : InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderBy(r => r.ProductSold).ToList();
        var tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>(InventoryList);
        chosenCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var item in tempCollection)
        {
            Inventory _inventory = new Inventory
            {
                ProductDescription = item.ProductDescription,
                Supplier = item.Supplier,
                ProductSold = item.ProductSold,
                ProductCost = item.ProductCost,
                ProductRetail = item.ProductRetail,
                TotalRetail = item.TotalRetail
            };
            chosenCollection.Add(_inventory);
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = chosenCollection;
        if (soldAsc)
        {
            descAsc = true;
            suppAsc = true;
            soldAsc = false;
        }
        else
        {
            soldAsc = true;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to reduce the `booleans` to be used? There will be times that the columns will increase or decrease, thus the change in `boolean` count. I went with this method so that I can check whether the same column is clicked again or not.

***Note:*** The `isDaily` changes based from date, but is not included here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need three methods for sorting because the only difference between them is the property that you use for sorting. You might as well have only one method that takes a `Fuc<Inventory, TKey>` as a key selector and use it with  `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
private void SortInventory<TKey>(Func<Inventory, TKey> keySelector)
{
    ObservableCollection<Inventory> chosenCollection = (isDaily) ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;
    List<Inventory> InventoryList = chosenCollection.ToList();
    InventoryList = (descAsc) ? InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList() : InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();


    .. unchanged
}
```

Then you can modify your `switch` as

```
switch (sortBy)
{
    case "Description":
        SortInventory(x => x.ProductDescription);
        break;
    .. other cases
}
```

or create helper methods:

```
SortInventoryByDescription() => SortInventory(x => x.ProductDescription);
```

and use them in the `switch`

```
switch (sortBy)
{
    case "Description":
        SortInventoryByDescription();
        break;
    .. other cases
}
```

You should also be more specific when naming your methods. `SortDescription` means you sort descriptions and not something else **by** description which is what you are actually doing.

---

> ```
> ObservableCollection<Inventory> chosenCollection = (isDaily) ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;
> ```

You are not using this `ObservableCollection` at all so the variable can simply be `var chosenCollection` or if you really want to use explicit types then `IEnumerable<Inventory>` is all you need for sorting.

---

Now let's get improve the `descAsc` variable. This one is really confusing. Is it *asc* when it's `true` or `false`? It'd be much easier to use if you named it `isAscending`.

Then is the same line:

> ```
> InventoryList = (descAsc) ? InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList() : InventoryList = InventoryList.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
> ```

you don't need so many assignments. It's fine to do the ordering first and then call `ToList` only once at the end and assign the result to `InvenotryList` also only once:

```
InventoryList = (isAscending ? chosenCollection.OrderBy(keySelector) : chosenCollection.OrderByDescending(keySelector)).ToList();
```

Further below I don't understand why you are recreating the `Inventory` with the `foreach` loop. Maybe it's a requirement.

---

One of the most confusing parts is the one where you create the `tempCollection` from `InventoryList` and copy it to the `chosenCollection`.

Why don't you simply use LINQ to do this so it could be as simple as:

```
var chosenCollection = isDaily ? SortedDailyCollection : SortedCustomCollection;    
var sortedInventory = isAscending ? chosenCollection.OrderBy(keySelector) : chosenCollection.OrderByDescending(keySelector);

var sortedInventoryCopies = 
    from item in sortedInventory
    select new Inventory
    {
        ProductDescription = item.ProductDescription,
        Supplier = item.Supplier,
        ProductSold = item.ProductSold,
        ProductCost = item.ProductCost,
        ProductRetail = item.ProductRetail,
        TotalRetail = item.TotalRetail
    };

listView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>(sortedInventoryCopies);
```

You don't need any lists or multiple observable-collections. Just sort the inventory and pass the result to the final observable-collection which will become your `ItemsSource`.

---

> ```
> if (descAsc)
> {
>     descAsc = false;
>     suppAsc = true;
>     soldAsc = true;
> }
> else
> {
>     descAsc = true;
> }
> ```

I cannot reason about this part. It's too confusing. You should rethink it and also change the names to full words instead of abbreviations.

---

Another issue is that your code isn't consistant. Once you use full type names and another time just `var`. Why not use `var` everywhere? Then you mix *PascalCasing* `InventoryList`  with *camelCasing* `chosenCollection` for your variables. You should also use variable names that better describe things they hold. `SortedDailyCollection` or `SortedCustomCollection` don't say anything about the content of the collection. `SortedDailyInventory` or `SortedCustomInventory` sound much better.

Comment: The `descAsc` *(descriptionAscending is the full term)* part is used to check if the same column is clicked again, sorting the column in descending or ascending order. The default for each click in a column is ascending that is why I change the values to `true` to the other `bool`, then making the column's `bool` to false so that when it is clicked again, it orders it in descending order

Comment: @Swellar oh, I see, I thought it meant descending-ascending... that's why you should not use abbreviations, especially unclear ones like this, that are known only to you ;-)

Comment: That makes sense, I'll remember that. I'll make it descriptive even if it became longer.